# Sound only plays in iPhone Simulator, Not on Device

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, core-audio

All,

I have a method that plays an .aiff file. All works fine in the simulator but when i run on the device, no sound is rendered. I am running iOS 7 on my device and it works running iOS 7 in the simulator.

Any Ideas?

Here is the method:

```
-(void) playNote:(NSString *)noteVal {

    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundId);
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(__bridge CFStringRef)noteVal, CFSTR("aiff"), NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundId);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
    noteVal = nil;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13109436/900873

Comment: It was that the silencer was on. Thanks